# How can I fix an Invalid implicit conversion from int256 to uint256 requested

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

I'm creating a modified version of Sushiswap's Masterchef V2 contract using solidity 0.8.4.

```
user.rewardDebt = user.rewardDebt.add(
      int256(_amount.mul(pool.accAmountPerShare) / accHarpyPerBlock)
    );
```

In the deposit function, I'm getting the following error in the code snippet above:

```
TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from int256 to uint256 requested.
   --> contracts/CDI.sol:236:7:
    |
236 |       int256(_amount.mul(pool.accAmountPerShare) / accTokenPerBlock)
    |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

The types of each variable are:

```
uint256 user.rewardDebt
uint256 _amount
uint256 pool.accAmountPerShare
uint256 accTokenPerBlock
```

Which alternative to perform this calculation successfully?

Comment: The variable user.rewardDebt is named in such a way that it should be either positive (reward) or negative (debt). But its type is uint256... so unsigned. At the same time you are adding an amount explicitly casted to int256 (signed) to it. Is this a typo in your question or is it your actual code ?

Comment: This is not a typo it is my real code. This code snippet was explicitly copied from MasterChef V2. Apparently it works correctly on solidity 0.6.12, but not on version 0.8.4.

You can check the excerpt at [this link](https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap/blob/canary/contracts/MasterChefV2.sol), on line 238.

Comment: From the link your sent me : https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap/blob/canary/contracts/MasterChefV2.sol#L35 check the highlighted line. rewardDebt is int256 not uint256.

Comment: Okay, that was really helpful. I hadn't noticed the incorrect typing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct typing of `user.rewardDebt` is actually `int256` instead of `uin256`.